# Why different android versions display different GUI?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-3.0-honeycomb

Please have a look at the following code

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/billTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/billTextView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/billEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:longClickable="false" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tenTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10%"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fifteenTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15%"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/twentyTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="20%"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/tipTxtView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tip10EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tip15EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tip20EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/totalTextView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total10EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total15EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total20EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/customTextView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:progress="18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customTipTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="a"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipCustomTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/tipCustomTextView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tipCustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalCustomTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/totalCustomTextView"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/totalCustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The project is created using Android Version 3.2.

This is how it get displayed in Galaxy Nexus, which is set to Android version 2.3.3

[image]

This is how it get displayed in Galaxy Nexus, which is set to Android version 3.2

[image]

As you can see, in that new version one, the GUI is bit upset. It seems like the components are overlapping. That is why it doesn't show the borders of the components. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, **this is normal**. The visual appearance of Android has been greatly polished with *Android 4.0*. It has nothing to do with your code directly. Android does this automatically.

If you want all your users to see the old style, you can set down the *targetVersion* within the `<uses-sdk>` tag of your manifest file. However, I discourage you from doing this.

Comment: As another option, you can also take the time to theme your application extensively, creating a (mostly) consistent experience across all devices if you're willing to put the effort into it.

Comment: @Blumer: Thanks for the reply :). But the app is designed with version 3.2!!!! You mean even if it is designed using 3.2 and tested in 3.2 emulator, this is what I can get?

Comment: @poitroae: OK, you mean this is the new style? When you code the GUI, this is the GUI we get, is that is? Please help!

Comment: @poitroae: ohh my god :( I don't like this style :(